# Why temp object created when we have const reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Why temp object created when we have const reference?
and why we have const ref in copy constructor?

```
String::String(const String& old_str) 
{ 
    size = old_str.size; 
    s = new char[size+1]; 
    strcpy(s, old_str.s); 
}
```

Comment: One question by question.

Comment: If the copy-constructor takes its argument by value, the value needs to be copied, which invokes the copy constructor, which takes its argument by value, which means it needs to be copied...

Comment: I think we need to see more of how your String class is defined.

Comment: *"Why temp object created when we have const reference?"* not the case, but temporary can bind to const reference.

Comment: Where in your code do you believe a temp object is created?

Comment: And a copy constructor can take its argument by non-const reference, but then you can't use prvalues as arguments. Assuming your `String` class have the appropriate conversion constructor, then something like `String my_string = "foo";` would not work if you use non-const reference argument.

Comment: Don't you think, it will be a paradox to send a copy of argument for copy ctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Const reference in copy constructor is needed to be declared with const qualifier because when you are making a copy of the object from the other object it will not make any logical sense to modify the original object. Const guarantees that you will not accidentally change the contents of the old string old_str.

If new object is created outside the copy constructor than it is the expected behavior. We are creating a new object from the original one which is passed by old_str reference